Confused with this usage of 余裕がない
From the anime Black Lagoon, main character asks poor local merchant in town how much the price of the (likely stolen) goods they're selling are:

(To merchant)ヌンさんそれ新品 ？ いくら ？
高いよどうせ盗品なんだろ ？
(To self)そうだよな
今だって懐に余裕ないわけじゃないもんなあ
Mr. Lun, is
that new? How much? That's too much.
I'll bet it's stolen.
Oh, well.
It's not like anyone has anything to spare in their wallets.

This makes no sense to me. For this to work with the translation shouldn't it be 余裕ある? It's not only translated that way but only makes sense that way too. Otherwise it turns into "It's not like they don't have spare room in their pockets", meaning they do have spare room, which again makes no sense because the people living in the town the main character is commenting on are poor and needy.
The only other thing I can think of is that 懐に余裕ない actually means something like "there is no (physical) spare room in their moneybooks", meaning that they do have money (it's full of money, no room for anything else). What is the correct interpretation?

Is it possible that the main character is talking about his own financial situation that allows him to pay the high price perhaps to help the seller?

Perhaps but the use of もん makes me feel mores so he’s talking about the situation of the city since he recently arrived. I checked the audio too

I haven't watched the anime and can't be sure, but if he's saying "今だって懐に余裕ないわけじゃないもんなあ" to himself, he's saying "it isn't that[-わけじゃない]  <I am not 懐に余裕ある-state> ", so  he can't say he cannot afford that.  懐に余裕ない does mean he's lacking the money, but it's negated here. The negations in the translation <<It's not like anyone has anything to spare in their wallets.>>, confuses me a lot, so I can't say it's wrong or right.

As aguijonazo and Yosh said, this sentence normally means "It's not that I don't have any financial leeway for now" (i.e., "I do have some money to spare right now"). If you don't think it makes sense in the context, please share more context. The episode number and the timestamp would be the most helpful.

Of course. It’s episode 4 of the first season, starts at 3:15.

OK, I watched the specified part (episode 4 of the first season, 3:15-).
The corresponding part goes like this:

Rock: ヌンさんそれ新品？  Nun-san, is it new?
Nun: (Nods)
Rock: いくら？ How much?
Nun: (shows five fingers)
Rock: 高いよ．どうせ盗品なんだろ？ That's too expensive. It's stolen anyway, right?
Nun: (shows four, then five, most likely 4.5)
Rock: (Looking at the sky) そうだよなぁ，今だって懐に余裕ないわけじゃないもんなあ…
Rock (Gesturing something like a shrug) やめとこ，どうせレヴィに甘ちゃん呼ばわりされるのがオチだ． (Leaves)

As far as I can tell, here, Rock first considers actually buying it because it isnt' that he cannot afford it, and then reconsiders (やめとこ), thinking that he would just end up having Revy criticise him as naiive.
So, here, 今だって懐に余裕ないわけじゃない means "(Even) now, it isn't that I'm financially too limited" = he does have the money.
Aside from this specific episode, 懐に余裕がない always means that the subject is financially limited and not the other way round.
